MUI Form posting nested JSON
I can't seem to find an answer that actually works for my situation, and it should be easy.
I am using a MUI React MultiSelect Dropdown in my form.  I am able to extract the nested JSON using values.materials[0].materialId, which only seems to be passing the first value rather than the array of values.  I am trying to use this to checkmark the existing values in the dropdown.  That is Problem #1.
Problem #2 is I am unable to write the information back in the same format as the original values, it always seems to create a new value.
The format of my date is:
  "materials": [
    {
      "materialId": 1,
      "materialName": "Material 1"
    },
    {
      "materialId": 2,
      "materialName": "Material 2"
    }
  ]

Here Is My Component:
<DropdownMultiSelect
    onChange={handleInputChange}
    label='Materials'
    name='materials[0].materialId'
    // name='materials.[0].materialId'
    // name='materials[0][materialId]'
    // name='materials[materialId]'
    // name='materials.materialId'
    // value={values["materials"]["materialId"]}
    value={values.materials[0].materialId} // only seems to pass a single value, not the array
    prompt='Materials...'
    url={materialsURL}
/>

The problem is, that no matter what I try, rather than replacing the nested Jason values for materials, it creates a new value using the name I have declared in the component  You can see all the different variations I have tried.
  "materials": [
    {
      "materialId": 1,
      "materialName": "Material 1"
    },
    {
      "materialId": 2,
      "materialName": "Material 2"
    }
  ],
  "materials[0].materialId": 1
  "materials[0].materialName": "Material 1 (edited)"

or these other variations:
    "materials.[0][materialId]": 1
    "materials[0][materialId]": 1
    "materials[materialId]": 1
    "materials.materialId": 1


Here is my Change Handler
function FormFunctions() {
  const [values, setValues] = React.useState({} as any);


  const handleInputChange = e => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setValues({
      ...values,
      [name]: (typeof value === 'string' ? (value).replace(/ +(?= )/g, '').trimStart() : value)
    });

How can I write the name where it will replace the existing materials values as nested JSON and help me pass the existing values as an array???

It looks like you have possibly seen semantics relating to form management libs like react-hook-form and formik and conflated that behavior with the default behaviour of the underlying components. Without a form lib like those, its up to you to bind a handleInputChange to deeply set the data. Please edit your question with the handleInputChange implementation, and include any useStates it references etc.

it is possible, I created my change handler to prior to having to deal with nested JSON data

Can you useContext to update the dropdown array (values.materials) outside of the current component?
